# Photo vault security

Tags: privacy, ios

I moved pictures from my stock iOS photos app to an old photo vault app. I used my LTE to move the pictures and was wondering if whenever I opened the app on WiFi, if my school could potentially see all of the images moved there. I can move pictures from my stock photos app to the photo vault while on airplane mode so I don’t believe they are being uploaded anywhere else. I have also deleted the images in question from my phone and all clouds.

The app in question has been removed in the App Store and is pretty old but here’s a link about it:
https://appadvice.com/app/secret-calculator-photo-vault-lock-hide-pictures/470578793

Answer (score 1):

> I can move pictures from my stock photos app to the photo vault while on airplane mode so I don’t believe they are being uploaded anywhere else.

If you're not transfering your photos through your school's Wifi, they can't see something. Just be sure, this app doesn't do any background connections with their *"cloud"*.

The question you *actually* need to consider -to prevent sniffing when transfering- is if this *old photo vault app* transfer the photos through HTTPS protocol. As the link didn't provide any usefull information about the security they're using, you can achieve that with one of most well known programs that analyze packets (eg. Wireshark). If it's using https; you're *-propably-* safe from sniffing.
*(except all the other factors; where are they storing the photos, who got access, what kind of encryption etc.)*

Your school can -and should- log the transfers and see where the connections are going or coming.

Comment: Right, I figured they’d be able to see something whether the app uses http or https while transferring the files over their Wifi. Just by opening the app on their Wifi, would they be able to see the images? I don’t have my own network currently and am unsure whether using Starbucks wifi would work

Comment: @Mike In general, noone in the network can see what applications you're opening on your phone, and collect information from them. **But,** propably any application that synchronise files between two devices, when they're starting, they check -most of times- automatically if files are still same in both locations. 
Unfortunately, I did my _little_ research on this application, and didn't managed to find any useful information about the topic.

Comment: How is that so? I thought every time an app connected to the internet, something was logged. Additionally, this is the only device that I have this app on, so will it still check?

Comment: When I said between two devices, I meant your phone and application's server. So, it will probably check anytime you open it for new files through Internet.

Comment: *But still* is really _product specific_ question and no one probably can answer what this app actually doing. We can only assume.

Comment: I downloaded fiddler on my laptop and was able to view the traffic. All I can see is 21 bytes going out from my phone and that is not nearly enough to be an image and just reads state:disabled. Do you have any idea what this means? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwqNe.png

Comment: Excuse me for my delay, you should probably update your question with every new findings. **However**, as far as I can guest, that request to app's server doesn't say much, it's _just_ checking state of synchronization or API.